# Check Constraint question

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Как сделать ограничение уникальности только на какое-то одно определенное значение в колонке, а не на всю колонку.
К примеру есть таблица с колонками "имя" и "должность"
и должность директор должна быть вписана только 1 раз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужен именно `CHECK`, то можно как-то так:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckManager()
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @res int;
   SELECT @res = COUNT(*) FROM [таблица] WHERE [должность] = N'директор';
   RETURN @res;
END

ALTER [таблица] ADD CONSTRAINT ck_manager CHECK (dbo.CheckManager() <= 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать Filtered Index:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SomeIndex] ON [dbo].[Сотрудники]
(
    [Должность] ASC
)
WHERE ([Должность]=N'Директор')
```

или, как вариант, триггер на INSERT/UPDATE + проверку на существование значения